# Key frames disappeared from timeline

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

I'm working on creating some animations for my character using the Action Editor.  I was editing an animation and everything was working as normal - I'm in pose mode and the keyframes of the animation I was working on were being displayed in the timeline.  I really can't remember what I did next, but I got distracted and when I next looked at the timeline, none of my keyframes were there.  Instead at the very bottom of the timeline there is an upward pointing arrow next to the text F_00.

My keyframes still appear in the dope sheet and the animations still play when I press the spacebar.  I can also still switch between animations in the Action Editor.  I am selecting the pose bones to animate them just as before, I just cannot see anything in the timeline.

I'm guessing I accidentally changed some setting.  How do I get my timeline back to normal?

[image]

Comment: you've enabled the Only Selected option in the Dope Sheet (blue arrow icon), only the keyframes of the selected bone will be displayed, it may be the problem? Or you've pushed the action into the NLA and you need to select it again?

Comment: Well, it started working again.  Not sure what went wrong or how it got fixed.  I'm pretty sure I didn't push anything onto the NLA.  Nothing appeared there at least.